How can I effectively utilize Google Apps Script as a callback URL for handling API responses or webhooks?
I'm exploring the possibility of using Google Apps Script as a callback URL to receive data from external APIs or webhooks. I want to process this incoming data within Google Apps Script, potentially integrating it with Google Sheets. However, Has anyone successfully implemented a similar solution before?
Any tips, best practices, or sample code snippets would be greatly appreciated!

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand I'm exploring the possibility of using Google Apps Script as a callback URL to receive data from external APIs or webhooks., for example, how about Web Apps? You can see about the Web Apps in the official document. Ref.
